# Calling a WCF WebService in PHP via wsHttpBinding

Tags: .net, php, wcf, wshttpbinding

I have a WCF webservice I can connect to it via basicHttp, but not wsHttp. I try to conenct to it via wshttp via the following:

```
$service = new SoapClient
("http://service.companyname.local:6666/Service/?wsdl",
 array(
         "location" => "http://service.companyname.local:6666/Service/WCF",

    "trace" => true,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
     )
);
```

The call to the SoapClient constructor returns fine. When I try to call one using $client->FunctionName, the page just sits there loading for quite a while, and eventually returns the error "Error Fetching http headers". What exactly is this supposed to mean and how do I fix it? (Consuming the service from .Net client works perfectly.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [default config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx) on wsHttpBinding uses advanced WS-Security and WS-Addressing features that aren't understood by the vanilla PHP SoapClient. There are other PHP-accessible SOAP clients that might be able to work (Apache Axis2+Rampart/C, for instance), or you can try to shut off some of the incompatible wsHttpBinding features (message security is probably the first). Not to say that it won't work, but you'll probably need some trial-and-error to get it all working right.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I checked, php didn't support `wsHttpBinding`

Comment: Svetlozar, Where did you check? Did you write some code, look on google and get as far as I did? Did you check in the PHP documentation? some mailing list? If it can't be done, I want to know why it can't be done.

Comment: Agreed, it would be good to have some substance to this sweeping statement.  PHP and WCF is an area i am struggling with, there are lots of workarounds on the web that seem to be a result of people 'fiddling' until they get it to work, but no one has so far been able to identify step-by-step exactly what the issues are in the interaction.