# How interopable is WS-Security?

Tags: wcf, security, soap, ws-security

I've recently worked on a project where a WCF service was involved, and a `wsHttpBinding` was used for authentication. A third party consuming the service with PHP complained that this approach didn't work out of the box in PHP and that it wasn't interopable enough (they preferred a RESTful approach, passing credentials with GET..)

I've never consumed a service with PHP, does their argument hold any water?

To expand:

Not being able to get something working out of the box in your language/environment isn't necessarily a good argument for lack of interopability and I'm not really convinced by them. I'm curious how interopable it is on a broader scale though, as I want my service to be easily consumable not just by .NET clients.

Additional note:

I use TransportWithMessageCredential, the credentials are verified IN the service, and not by IIS. What is the preferred way of supplying credentials to a RESTful service in this manner? (should this be a separate question?). I'm just wondering if it even IS a viable alternative in this scenario.

Comment: PHP is a scripting language. It wouldn't shock me to find it doesn't implement international standards out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that REST is very easy to implement on a wide range of programming platforms and operating systems (including, for instance, PHP on a Linux box, which is a very common setup).

WS-Security, as an extension to SOAP, is a standardized protocol and there exist implementations for other platforms than .NET. However, the range of free libraries here is very limited (for PHP, I don't know any) and it surely means more effort to connect to a WS-Security service than to a simple REST service, at least if the service uses protocol features that go beyond the scope of plain SOAP.

One more thing: HTTP has authentication support built in, so you can absolutely implement an authenticated RESTful service without adding credentials to the requested URL.

Comment: I've updated my question, but transport itself does not need to be authenticated, rather the message. The service uses `TransportWithMessageCredential`, and the service validates credentials.

Comment: I doubt that it will be easy to use such a feature with a non-.NET language like PHP. If you want to know how you can achieve something comparable with REST, that would be worth a new question. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933234/calling-a-wcf-webservice-in-php-via-wshttpbinding for more information.

Comment: REST is not a protocol. It's simply a technique.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some of my clients too (Also calling my service from PHP).

So we just exposed an additional **basicHttpBinding** Endpoint.

I use *Transport* security with *UsernamePassword* authentication in that Endpoint.

Comment: My service still requires message security, and such is only available with the `wsHttpBinding`

Comment: @diggingforfire - why won't you use Transport security? It's not possible to use wsHttpBinding with PHP. I use Transport (SSL) for the encryption and Username/Password for the authentication.

Comment: The credentials need to be handled by the service, not by the webserver (IIS), so they need to be in the message. It's still HTTPS though (you can't use message security without HTTPS)

Comment: @diggingforfire - My service is self hosted in a process and I check the Username/Password myself. I'm sure you can do it with IIS too, probably you can do it by implementing your own UserNamePasswordValidator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx).

Comment: BTW, You can use Message security without SSL. To do so you need to change the security mode from TransportWithMessageCredentials to Message.